# Why return error result when use _routing field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Such as url `index-0/_search?routing=24320`,i search data from `24230` `routing`,but the result is

```
"_index": "index-0",
"_type": "member",
"_id": "40865630",
"_score": 1,
"_routing": "22500",
```

Why `22500` match the search condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when specifying `?routing=24320` in your search query, you're basically selecting the single shard on which documents with the routing value of 24320 have been stored.

Now, since your query doesn't specify any other constraints, you're basically getting all documents stored on that shard, which obviously means that you also get documents whose routing value is 22500 (and probably others, too).

Comment: Thank you.I have another question,For example,i have 100000 docs,use `_route` field to write data into one shard or not use?One shard just use one server's resource?

Comment: if you have a single shard, using routing is useless since all docs would go to the single shard anyway... Basically, one shard = one Lucene index and consumes CPU/RAM resources on your host.

Comment: I have 5 shards,and shards store in different hosts. Use `route`?

Comment: I suggest you read up on routing a little bit in order to know whether that fits your use case or not: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/routing-value.html